# Qual a diferença entre git pull e git pull --rebase

Tags: git

No git eu tenho a possibilidade de fazer um `git pull origin master` e um `git pull --rebase origin master`. Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os dois.

Comment: O primeiro faz um merge (ou `fast forward`). O segundo faz uma "reescrita de histórico", mudando a base das mudanças para o ponto do branch remoto (operação essa chamada de `rebase`)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Para entender as diferenças, nada melhor que um [exemplo simples](https://qualidadegarantida.blogspot.com/2014/01/git-rebase-vs-merge-diferencas-e-qual.html).

Imagine que você está fazendo commits na branch master com outras pessoas da sua equipe. Para simplificar o cenário, vocês estão usando o GitHub para sincronizar todos os commits da branch master, usando-o como repositório principal.

Sendo assim, digamos que existem os seguintes commits neste momento no `master` do GitHub.

```
M1<---M2<---M3
```

Após fazer o clone do repositório, você faz mais 2 commits locais (C1 e C2). Na sua máquina, o repositório ficará parecido com o seguinte:

```
                  .---C1<---C2
                 /
M1<---M2<---M3<-´
```

Contudo, no GitHub, outros desenvolvedores já fizeram o `push` de mais 3 commits no master enquanto você tem ainda seus 2 commits que estão apenas no seu repositório local. Na branch `master` do GitHub, teremos então a seguinte situação:

```
M1<---M2<---M3<---M4<---M5<---M6
```

Com o **git pull**, o Git vai gerar um novo commit que concentra as alterações que ocorreram frutos deste merge dos commits C1 e C2 com os commits M4, M5 e M6. O comando `git pull` faz, por trás dos bastidores, duas coisas: um `git fetch` e um `git merge`.

Na etapa de `git fetch`, você irá receber as alterações e terá no seu repositório a seguinte situação:

```
                  .---C1<---C2
                 /
M1<---M2<---M3<-´---M4<---M5<---M6
```

Na etapa de `merge`, seu repositório gerará o commit M7, resultado deste merge:

```
                  .----C1<---C2<----.
                 /                   \
M1<---M2<---M3<-´---M4<---M5<---M6<---`M7
```

Mas, em cenários diferentes, nem sempre o Git gera este commit de merge. Muitas vezes apenas você alterou a branch master, incluindo novos commits. Então ao fazer `git pull`, o git faz uma operação *fast forward*, simplesmente falando que seu último commit é o final da branch `master`:

```
                  .----C1<---C2
                 /            |       
M1<---M2<---M3<-´             |
                           [master]
```

O **git rebase** é uma espécie de `merge` também, mas usa uma lógica diferente. Ao invés de gerar um novo commit, ele reaplica cada um dos commits da branch local "em cima" (no topo) do último commit da branch remota.

Ou seja, se temos 2 commits (C1 e C2), eles serão aplicados a partir do commit M7.

Sendo assim, ao realizar o rebase, temos a situação:

```
                                            .----C1’<---C2’
                                           /
M1<---M2<---M3<_--M4<---M5<---M6<---M7<-´
```

Notem que chamei o C1 e C2 agora de C1’ e C2’. Motivo? Após o rebase, estes commits não são os mesmos commits originais. Serão commits totalmente novos, até mesmo com o SHA (identificador único e hash) diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a [documentação oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalsetruemergespreserveinteractive), **SE** o ramo local estiver configurado para acompanhar (*track*) as alterações do ramo remoto **E** o ramo remoto tiver recebido algum *rebase* desde o último *fetch* que você realizou no seu repositório local, **ENTÃO** *--rebase* fará o comando *pull* utilizar estas informações para evitar reaplicar as alterações não locais.

De modo mais pragmático e em outras palavras: *git pull --rebase* é pra ser usado quando se deseja atualizar (*pull*) um ramo local com um ramo remoto que, antes de ser enviado para a rede (*push*), sofreu mesclagem por *rebase*.

Como não se deve usar *rebase* em ramos utilizados por mais de um desenvolvedor, tanto *git rebase* quanto *git pull --rebase* devem ser usados apenas em "feature/topic branches".

O uso de *git pull --rebase* está fortemente associado à necessidade de um desenvolvedor, que utiliza mais de um computador em seu dia-a-dia, de manter atualizada a situação local de um ramo em que trabalha em máquinas diferentes (exemplo: quado o desenvolvedor alterna entre trabalho remoto e presencial).